# Mod rewriting a link with query to another subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got links with a query string that I would like to rewrite to a different subdomain. I've tried the following :

```
RewriteRule ^/forum/viewtopic.php(.*)$ http://sub2.domain.com/viewtopic.php$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

as well as :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic.php(.*) http://sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?%1
```

As you can imagine, it didn't fly. Most of the examples I've seen involved specifying the actual query string, however, my links have several variables passed and not always in the same order. Is it possible to rewrite a URL based on viewtopic.php?(anything onward)

**Original Links :**

```
sub1.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=123&sid=c75edda9

sub1.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.phpt=321&start=0&postdays=0&sid=6e97b05

sub1.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45&view=next&sid=f799
```

**New Links :**

```
sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=123&sid=c75edda9

sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=321&start=0&postdays=0&sid=6e97b05

sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45&view=next&sid=f799
```

Comment: This rule worked.

`code` RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic.php(.*)$ http://sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php%1 [R,L] `code`

Answer (score 1):

As simple as :

```
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic.php$ http://sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php [R=301, L]
```

No need for any [QSA] since you don't modify the Query string.

Comment: I modified the rule, and still no go. It goes to the new page, but strips out the query string. `code` RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ sub2.domain.com/forum/viewtopic.php? [R,L] `code`

Comment: Loose the `?` or it will replace the QueryString by empty.